# QoS implementation algorithm

Tags: algorithms, networking

I'm working on an application, that does IP routing and QoS. Today we have the QoS implemented, with 3 priorities (low, normal and high) and for each level we create a Queue and as soon as the packages are queued, we send it forward in a FIFO way (the scheduler spend 60% of time with the high queue, 30% the time with normal and 10% with the low queue). It works, but as FIFO it has some drawbacks like:

- An aggressive traffic will fill in the queue and all other flows with the same priority will be stucked
- under high usage, TCP will slow down and UDP will keep flooding our Queue. It means in the end UDP flows will have better priorization then TCP flows

I was thinking a way to improve it and my idea is to implement a [SFQ](http://opalsoft.net/qos/DS-25.htm) with the following algorithm:

- keep the high, normal, low, but they aren't just 3 queues, but one per (seen) protocol
- The scheduler still spending 60% of time we spend with the high queues, 30% the time with normal and 10% with the low queues. But now, it does a round-robin between the queues with the same priority. The choosen Queue, will still forward the packets in a FIFO way.

drawbacks from this implementation:

- it is more expensive to the CPU

Am I missing something? Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Hurst or long range dependent network traffic](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=long%20range%20dependent%20network%20traffic&gws_rd=ssl) for example [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6101594).  If it is your problem, then you cannot reduce long range dependent traffic with queueing policies.

Comment: the difference is that my application will be running as first hop of a network not in a backbone. I think the paper is related with high-speed networks and i'm sitting on the edge of the network.

Comment: It maybe worth doing a tests on your data.  If you are assuming a Normal distribution of traffic, you will underestimate the size of your buffers.  Hurst work was on a dam over the rive Nile so just "one" source ^_~ yet the flooding data was long range dependent.  Then again, you maybe right and it does not matter.

Comment: definitely i didn't discard it :-)